# Angular material table paginator is not updating after filter

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am filtering table data source using a multiselect selectbox value. Table records are getting updated when I select the options from select box. But paginator is not getting updated.

```js
 @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;

ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (tdata: Catalog, filter: string) => {
        return this.filters.length > 0 ?
            this.filters.some(e => e === tdata.type) :
            true;
    };

}

applyFilter() {
    this.tdataSource.filter = 'trigger filter';
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-label>Filters</mat-label>
   <mat-select multiple [(value)]="filters">
   <mat-option  *ngFor="let item of options" [value]="item" (click)="applyFilter(item)">
   {{item}}
   </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

In below image I am filtering only database. Table is getting updated based on filters. But paginator is showing all the records.

And also if I select all check box in table header its selecting all records instead of selecting 4 records which is shown in UI.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried initializing paginator again in your filter method:

```
applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
  this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  setTimeout(() => this.dataSource.paginator=this.paginator;
  setTimeout(() => this.dataSource.sort = this.sort);
}
```